# NoReverseMatch when using with tag to set URL pattern name

Tags: django, django-templates

I am getting an error saying:

```
NoReverseMatch at /books/
Reverse for 'urlvar' not found. 'urlvar' is not a valid 
view function or pattern name.
```

I guess the `{% with %}` tag is not working well in books/index.html
but I don't know how to solve this.

this is my code:

books/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from books import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.BooksModelView.as_view(), name='index'),

url(r'^book/$', views.BookList.as_view(), name='book_list'),
url(r'^author/$', views.AuthorList.as_view(), name='author_list'),
url(r'^publisher/$', views.PublisherList.as_view(), name='publisher_list'),

url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.BookDetail.as_view(), name='book_detail'),
url(r'^author/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.AuthorDetail.as_view(), name='author_detail'),
url(r'^publisher/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PublisherDetail.as_view(), name='publisher_detail'),
               ]
```

templates/books/index.html

```
{% extends 'base_books.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Books Management Systemt</h2>
<ul>
{% for modelname in object_list %}
    {% with 'books:'|add:modelname|lower|add:'_list' as urlvar %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'urlvar' %}">{{ modelname }}</a></li>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: where is name='urlvar' in urls?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @Alasdair I'm using 2.0.7

Comment: @HemanthSP where do i have to put name=urlvar?

Comment: Charlotte Lee please following below answer from Alasdair,

Answer (score 1):

`urlvar` is a variable, so you use `urlvar` in the `{% url %}` tag instead of the string `'urlvar'`.

```
<li><a href="{% url urlvar %}">{{ modelname }}</a></li>
```

You can construct the URL pattern name in the tag if you prefer, or keep the `with` tag if you find that more readable.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'books:'|add:modelname|lower|add:'_list' %}">{{ modelname }}</a></li>
```

Since you are using the `'books:` namespace when you reverse the urls, you should set [`app_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) in your `books/urls.py` file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from books import views

app_name = 'books'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

Comment: "Still not working" isn't enough information to help you. If you've removed the quotes then the error message will be different, so you should update your question with that information.

Comment: sorry, it is saying 'NoReverseMatch at /books/
'books' is not a registered namespace'

Comment: haha yes I didn't save it well. above comment says what different error I got after removing

Comment: You need to set `app_name` in your `urls.py`. See the updated answer.

Comment: In `books/urls.py`, see the example above